# Hazelcast ssl enterprise version

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, enterprise, hazelcast

Am using the trial version of hazelcast enterprise version for testing,

When I look into the documentation, it shows like

Properties props = new Properties();
...
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
config.getSocketOptions().setSocketFactory( new SSLSocketFactory( props ) );

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/ssl.html

Where as when I try to implement it, there is no such method after **getSocketOptions** as setSocketFactory, Then am not sure how to implement ssl in hazelcast 3.4.2 version, My trial periods are running out,,, not satisfied with the SSL feature of hazelcast.

Regards,
Harry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Harry,

Did you have a chance to go through Hazelcast ssl example https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/network-configuration/ssl ?

It uses [`BasicSSLContextFactory`](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/nio/ssl/BasicSSLContextFactory.html) implemented by hazelcast.

Comment: Thanks Vik Gamov, I implemented using SSL config (I will post that shortly). I come to knw that ssl is enterprise in hazelcast, But for the first one year I cannot buy a enterprise version, Is it possible to implement our ssl code for hazelcast. Is there any provision for it. Thanks again.

Comment: It would be best for you to implement your own`com.hazelcast.instance.NodeExtension` with custom `com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.SocketChannelWrapperFactory`. In your jar you need to put file named `com.hazelcast.instance.NodeExtension` contained fully qualified class name of NodeExtension implementation to the `META-INF/services` folder.

Comment: Thanks @vik gamov, But I just looked into the NodeExtension interface in hazelcast and there was a file with the 'com.hazelcast.instance.NodeExtension' in META-INF/services pointing to 'defaultNodeExtension' in it. To be frank, Am not able to understand your point completely, Can u elaborate it, If you have any example for implementing this pls do share with me. Your help is much appreciable. Thanks again...

Comment: My main goal is to establish SSL between Hazelcast server to Hazelcast server communication. Please do help me on the server to server communication part.

What are the changes I need to make it achievable,

You gave me a path for server to server communication using
'com.hazelcast.instance.NodeExtension' in META-INF/services

But still I dont understand its usage completely.

Comment: Please do help me on establishing SSL communication between Hazelcast server and Hazelccast server communication part.

I prefer using sTUNNEL, but if you have any other idea on establishing ssl between Hazelcast server to Hazelcast server communication please do share with me. My life is in trouble a week.

Thanks you so much @Vik Gamov .

Comment: Harry, 1) create jar project 2) Implements NodeExtensions (e.g. `MyCustomNodeExtension` interface (you can take a look on DefaultNodeExtension code (it's open) as example) 2) Implements custom `SocketChannelWrapperfactory` with our own SSL implementation 3) provide your fully qualified classname of your NodeExtension implementation in META-INF/services files, e.g. `com.harry.hazelcast.MyCustomNodeExtension` 4) compile and build jar 5) include with jar with Hazelcast cluster classpath  6) PROFIT!

Comment: Thank you Vik Gamov, I got your idea, I followed these step, I downloaded the code from 'https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast' I took a build on hazelcast using maven but it builds successfully but when I try to import the project in eclipse It shows lots of maven cyclic dependency error. Is there any other way we can make the change in the code.

Comment: Sorry, can't help here. I don't use Eclipse... BTW, you don't need to change hazelcast code. You need to create your own jar with `NodeExtension` implementation. Think about it as a plugin.

Comment: @VikGamov may you look please at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30369352/get-started-with-hazelcast-sourcecode?noredirect=1#comment48830581_30369352? I stucked with it and don't know what to do

Answer (score -1):

I tried using SSL config, It worked like a fly.

```
http://admin.hazelcast.com/docs/2.6/javadoc/index.html?com/hazelcast/config/SSLConfig.html
```

Comment: it's doc for 2.6 version. What Hazelcast version do you use?